# How to test if an object is persisted in database Symfony/PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.8

I'm using Symfony 2.8 and PHPUnit.

I have a function which persists and flushes an object "invoice".

I want to create a unit test which asserts that this invoice object is persisted and created in my database.

Unfortunately, the code of the said function is like 200 lines long so I won't post it.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?  The entity manager is already pretty well tested.  Mock it and test for calls to persist and flush.

Comment: "..the code of the said function is like 200 lines long ..." you really should refactor it

Comment: @xmike I know but I juste arrived as a trainee and I don't think it's a good idea to suggest that after 3 days at work :D

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something obvious, but can you not a) create a temporary empty DB (possibly with SQLite) b) persist your invoice c) query the DB to make sure record exists?

Answer (score 2):

Despite what you may think, you really dont need to actually test if things go into the db, the entity manager is unlikely to have broken and thats all youre really going to be testing.

However, you should test that your code is working correctly and at least trying to put data in the db correctly, to do this, mock the entity manager and the repository.

Symfony has a pretty epic guide in their docs - https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html

Hope this helps